# Prevent onclick, I am calling onselect function in dojo but after that function onclick also calling

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am calling `onselect` function in dojo but after that function `onclick` also calling how to prevent that `onclick` function, I am selecting row because I can't get event object, how to solve this?

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId(dojo.query('.sdTableDiv1')[0].children[0].children[3].id), 'onSelect', dojo.hitch(thisobj, "addTableShowAlert")); //function call
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) or just catch your `onclick` event and `return`. Like that :

```
elem.click((ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault(); //prevent default method
  return ; //Return method
});
```